# Google oAuth redirect_uri_mismatch error in chrome

Tags: oauth-2.0

I am trying to set google login to my website and it works in firefox without error but in chrome its giving me this error

> Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
>
> The redirect URI in the request:
> http://cgcrush.hub.loginradius.com/socialauth/validate.sauth did not
> match a registered redirect URI

Any idea?

## EDIT

I have cross checked and notice that if I am already logged in to google account on that browser than it is giving an error but without logged in to google it is working. This is strange.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

I found the solution and it was the url issue set in API

Comment: "it was the url issue set in API" > What does that mean? Does that mean you had to change the Redirect URIs in the Google API configuration?

Comment: What was it? What did you change it to? And Where did you change it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've found that loginradius gives link on "http://" and Google needs "https://" instead.
You only have to switch it to "https://" and it works! :)

my 2 cent

Nico